# Nginx access_log off - apply to a single URL without stopping it returning a response

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to switch off access_log for a single url in a laravel application.

The url is `/ignore/this/url`

I need it to simply - for this one URL - NOT log information in the access_log, but I do want it to be parsed and run as it would be normally.

The normal one is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
    access_log /vagrant/logs/access.log;
    error_log /vagrant/logs/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 32M;

    location / {
        root /vagrant/web;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php {
                fastcgi_pass unix:///var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
    location /ignore/this/url {
        root /vagrant/web;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        access_log off;

        location ~ \.php {
                fastcgi_pass unix:///var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
        }

    }
```

But this seems to be ignored.

I've tried adding it inside the main location block.

```
location / {
        root /vagrant/web;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    location /ignore/this/url {
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.php {
                fastcgi_pass unix:///var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
        }

    }
```

But then it will give me a 404 error "File not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http {
   map $uri $do_log {
      /ignore/this/url 0;
      default 1;
   }

   server {
      ...
      access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log combined if=$do_log;
      
   }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but it should have... Because of the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` every url was index.php. Finally I had to use the $request variable and set it to "GET /ignore/this/url HTTP/1.1" but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to anyone... The accepted answer worked for any static url I tried but my `$uri` variable came out as index.php each time for most of my PHP files as the URL is rewritten due to

`try_files  /index.php?$args;`

Finally I had to use the following modification of the accepted answer to get this working:

```
http {
   map $request $do_log {
      'GET /ignore/this/url HTTP/1.1' 0;
      default 1;
   }

   server {
      ...
      access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log combined if=$do_log;
      
   }
}
```

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/